# Can't understand isFinishing

Tags: java, android

I've been studying [Google IO 2012 code](http://code.google.com/p/iosched/)
In one of the activities (HomeActivity.java) they're doing as follows:

```
void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance)
{
   if(someCondition) {
      // start some other activity here
      finish(); // finish this activity
   }

   if(isFinishing()) return;

   // More code here
}
```

I wonder why they do not put `return` right after `finish()` but instead checking `isFinishing()` ?

Comment: That's... a very good question. My guess is that they put it there either because there *could* be multiple `finish()` calls, or because something else may finish this activity before it starts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An Activity can be finished in a number of ways.

[`finishActivity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finishActivity%28int%29) from an activity that has called startActivityForResult

`finishAffinity` and `finishFromChild`

So `isfinishing` is used to account for such cases.